# Path of .MDB file?

Tags: ms-access, networking, jet

I have an `.MDB` database file located on a network share.

I have an application installed on several machines on the network. This application accesses the `.MDB` database.  What is the best way to store the path of the `.MDB` file?  In the registry perhaps, or in an `.INI` file, or an environment variable?

Comment: Would you consider acccepting some answers to your questions? That would encourage others to help you.

Comment: @MaDa The common tag for Jet is ms-access, even though Jet may be more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Registry: Possible, but not so easy to edit/deploy
- INI: I would prefer this. Easy to edit, easy to deploy
- Environment Variable: Too complicated, above methods are better

Another way: as a command line parameter of your application.

Answer (score 2):

I would *strongly* discourage the use of either the Registry or an environment variable.

This is the kind of simple configuration information that INI files were designed to provide. Unless you're writing a .NET application, in which case [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) are probably a better bet.

Comment: What are your reasons against Registry or Enviornment Variables for this purpose?

Comment: @Craig: Microsoft has been advising for some time not to use the Registry to dump application configuration settings like this. I realize it's a bit contradictory; they encouraged it's use for a while, but then application developers started to abuse it and the Registry got too big for its own good. Tobias's answer also explains why it makes deployment a nightmare. And it's simply an abuse of environment variables to use them for application-level configuration purposes. In addition to all the other deployment issues, this is the problem of global variables writ large. There's just no reason.